# PULP SDK build process

Tags: riscv, pulp

I'm new to this website and it is the first time I've worked with the RISC-V processor. I'm following the tutorial of the PULP SDK build process "https://github.com/pulp-platform/pulp-sdk".
But, I'm blocked at the stage of SDK build when I tape the command "$ make all" and I can't understand what's mean these errors.

**Below the errors:**

```
sdk:json-tools:build: make all install
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pulp/project/pulpissimo/pulp-sdk/json-tools'
#### Building in /home/pulp/project/pulpissimo/pulp-sdk/build/sdk/json-tools
#### Release type is RelWithDebInfo
#### Installing to /home/pulp/project/pulpissimo/pulp-sdk/pkg/sdk/dev/install/ws
( cd /home/pulp/project/pulpissimo/pulp-sdk/build/sdk/json-tools ; make all  VERBOSE=0 )
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/pulp/project/pulpissimo/pulp-sdk/build/sdk/json-tools'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'all'.  Stop.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pulp/project/pulpissimo/pulp-sdk/build/sdk/json-tools'
Makefile:46: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pulp/project/pulpissimo/pulp-sdk/json-tools'
Reached EOF with exit status 2
FATAL ERROR: the command 'build' has failed
Makefile:6: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 255
```

**Thank you in advance**

Comment: We need more information from you, see [How to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Yup. Consider cutting down your case to minimum, while still getting the issue and share it, so we can actually see where the problem may be.

Answer (score 0):

Have you selected the target as advised [in the documentation](https://github.com/pulp-platform/pulp-sdk#target-and-platform-selection) before running `make all`?

By running `source configs/pulpissimo.sh` for example.

Comment: Yes, I selected the target as advised in the documentation before running *make all*. In fact, it was a Vivado cmake problem that starts automatically when I run the *make all* command and it's an old version of cmake.

I solved this problem by uncommenting the line *source /opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2018.3/settings64.sh*. The day I need to launch Vivado I have to run this line on the command line in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I selected the target as advised in the documentation before running `make all`. In fact, it was a Vivado cmake problem that starts automatically when I run the `make all` command and it's an old version of cmake.

I solved this problem by uncommenting the line **source /opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2018.3/settings64.sh**. The day I need to launch Vivado I have to run this line on the command line in the terminal.

Comment: This appears to be a reply to Valentin. He won't see it here - please delete it and use the `add a comment` link under his post.

Comment: I have retracted my NAA flag. This looked like it was not an answer because it contained a reply to another answer. I have removed that, and now think it is sufficient to stand alone as an answer.